# Ghidra view stack frame values

Tags: ghidra, debuggers, stack-variables

I'm learning reverse engineering, and I'm using Ghidra's debugger to analyze a running program. I want to view the values that are on the stack for a function, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I've tried to use the address in RSP to view the memory in the dynamic listing, but all I get is a section of memory that is grey with no values.

Example line from the dynamic listing:

```
      41dc0ef580 00              ??         00h
```

I'm debugging a win32 application using the ghidra (v10.2.2) debugger with dbgeng locally via GADP on windows. Read visible memory is enabled in the dynamic listing, and there are no errors in the debug console.

How can I view the values for a all variables in the stack frame for a running function?